# Meteor autoForm submitting to GET request + query string parameters

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

**Update:** I figured it out. I needed to add the collection parameter instead of the schema parameter. Once I added that all was well.

I have a form which renders properly. But when I click the submit button the code that should fire via the autoform hooks does not run (no console log statements are printed), and my browser is taken via a GET request to the same URL as the form itself, but with the contents of the form values added to the query string.

e.g. http://localhost:3000/courses/cqfr3FaSaGNjkHRWd/lessons/new?title=My+Title&summary=My+Summary&content=My+Content

**Why does the form not submit properly?**

I have a form that's basically identical to this one that works fine. In fact I copied and pasted most of the code from that form to create this form.

Here's my schema:

```js
Application.Schemas.Lessons = new SimpleSchema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    label: "Title"
  },
  summary: {
    type: String,
    label: "Summary"
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    label: "Content"
  },
  courseId: {
    type: Number,
    index: 1
  },
  lastUpdated: {
    type: Date,
    label: "Last Updated",
    autoValue: function () {
      return new Date();
    }
  }
});
```

Here I add the schema to a global set of schemas and attach it to the collection:

```js
Lessons = Application.Collections.Lessons = new Meteor.Collection('lessons');
Lessons.attachSchema(Application.Schemas.Lessons);
Lessons.allow({
  insert: function() {
    return true;
  },
  remove: function() {
    return true;
  }
});
```

Here's my form:

```html
<template name="lessonForm">
    {{# autoForm schema=Application.Schemas.Lessons id="lessonForm" type=action doc=lesson}}
      <fieldset>
          {{> afQuickField name="title"}}
          {{> afQuickField name="summary" rows=6}}
          {{> afQuickField name="content" rows=6}}
      </fieldset>
      <button class="btn btn-primary pull-left" type="submit">Submit</button>
    {{/autoForm}}
</template>

<template name="editLesson">
  <h1 class="page-header">Edit Lesson</h1>
    {{> lessonForm action="update" lesson=this}}
  <button class="delete btn btn-danger pull-right">Delete</button>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</template>

<template name="newLesson">
  <h1 class="page-header">New Lesson</h1>
    {{> lessonForm action="insert" }}
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</template>
```

Comment: `type=action doc=lesson` what this does?

Comment: from autoform docs
`type: Optional. One of "insert", "update", or "method". Setting the type to anything else or omitting it will call any onSubmit hooks`

Comment: If you have `onSubmit` hook can you post it

Comment: @Sasikanth

> If you have onSubmit hook can you post it  

No onSubmit hook setup.  

Re: the type parameter, you'll see that I pass the type value into the form via the action parameter. In the newLesson template you'll see that I have {{> lessonForm action="insert" }}. Passing the type in this way allows me to reuse the actual form template for both inserts and updates.  
  
Re: "type=action doc=lesson":  
  
I answered the type=action part in the previous paragraph. The doc=lesson part allows me to pass the lesson into the form. I'll post the router code in another comment